# External hdd: Difference "Get Info" Available space and "About This Mac - Storage

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, system-information

OS X El Capitan.

I have seen this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132303/why-do-i-get-different-available-used-spaces-with-disk-info-and-df), and it explains a bit (different reporting units), but there is an additional substantial discrepancy in the free HDD space of an external HD reported:

- `Get Info` : 11.22GB
- `df -h`    : 1.3Gi
- `About This Mac - Storage` : 1.42 GB

[image: Screenshot of the different disk free info]

So the differences between `About This Mac` and `df -h` can be according to the different units - but the `Get Info` is heavily off?

Any ideas what is going on there?

I know for a fact that the `df -h` and `About This Mac` are correct as I can not copy anything larger than the 1.4 Gb on the disk.

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

These are the hidden files and folders - the rest is stuff I put there:

```
$ ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 rainerkrug  staff       14340 Nov 10 14:51 .DS_Store
drwx------   5 root        staff         170 Nov 10 18:19 .Spotlight-V100
d-wx-wx-wt   2 root        staff          68 Nov 10 17:36 .Trashes
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 rainerkrug  staff         313 Mar 15  2015 .apdisk
drwx------  15 root        staff         510 Nov 10 18:24 .fseventsd
```

and their disk usage:

```
$ sudo du -sch .[!.]* *
 16K    .DS_Store
 11M    .Spotlight-V100
  0B    .Trashes
4.0K    .apdisk
 52K    .fseventsd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try **sudo mdutil -E /** on the terminal, to reindex Spotlight.

Comment: Why do you think spotlight has anything to do with it?

Comment: Because the report you look at on the get info window comes from the index. I'm telling you this because I had the same problem, 9.7GB of 'extra space' on every writeable disk connected on my computer, even a 1GB usb stick showed 10GB of free space, it was driving me crazy.

So, what I did besides disabling Time Machine and the backup space with 'sudo tmutil disablelocal' in Terminal was to reindex my Spotlight.

After that the readings went back to normal.

Comment: OK - this worked - I used ```sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/MyPassport2TB```. This deleted the index without touching the one from the internal hdd. If you could add the information  in the comment why this works, I will accept the answer.

Comment: Please make your answer more comprehensive and add why this helps.

Comment: The problem arises because Time Machine stores the backup that is going to save to the T.M. Disk the next time it's connected, for instance, if your next backup is 5GB, and you are away from home (where you have your Time Machine Disk), the backup is prepared before it's transferred to T.M. So, Finder shows you the space you have free subtracting the backup, because that's going to T.M.
Which I consider a dumb implementation from Apple, just because it leads to this kind of problem we had. I don't see the problem of reporting that space in T.M. and leave the borrowed space reported in Finder

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Finder **ignores all space taken up by backups.** As it detects and shows you in "About this Mac", you have about 9 GB of backups. "Get Info" reports the 2 GB of free space *and* 9 GB of backups. So, disabling and reenabling time machine may solve your problem, if it matters that much.

Comment: OK - that makes sense. But how can I delete the backups from the terminal if I need the space, apart from disabling and reenabling tIme Machine?

Comment: Just to add to it: this is ***not*** my system hdd - and on the external hdd there is no folder .MobileBackups as is on the internal hdd.

Comment: Try showing all hidden files and see what you find by: Opening Terminal and typing `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`. But, don't delete anything until you have researched what it does. I'm not near a computer right now, so I don't know what you'll find.

Comment: I have used ```ls -la``` and added the info in the question. but they are very small and negligible.

Comment: I just tried to disable and enable Time Machine Backups, and nothing changed on the **external hdd** - on the **internal** I gained about 12 GB, but nothing on the **exeternal**. I did a hdd check from ```Disk Utility``` and everything is OK.

Comment: Just to add a source to this, https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015 says "Because Time Machine removes local snapshots as needed, Finder and Get Info windows don't include them in their calculations. To see how much storage space local snapshots are using, choose About This Mac from the Apple menu, then click Storage. The space used by local snapshots is labeled Backups." I know that's for local backups, but I agree with @BobRon that it is likely the cause of the discrepancy.