# Disk space available: Finder shows way less than System Information

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, disk-space, system-information

The **Finder** currently shows only 81GB available (at the bottom of a folder's window) whereas **System Information** > **Storage** shows 455GB available.

Why does the Finder show so much less space available?

FYI: I'm running macOS 10.15.4 on an iMac with a 500GB drive.

Comment: This was a 2-part question. The first part is _why_ **System Information** differs from the **Finder** and _that_ part is _not_ a duplicate of the alleged other question.

Comment: Since these are two separate questions (and the second question is a duplicate), I would recommend editing out the second question so it can be reopened.

Comment: @abc - Even with the "Why" question, it would still be a dupe because a) it's addressed in several of the answers and b) that question also, has been addressed separately:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132303/why-do-i-get-different-available-used-spaces-with-disk-info-and-df/132309#132309

Comment: @Allan No. Neither question nor any answer there asks _specifically_ about **System Information** and the **Finder**. My **Disk Info** agrees with the **Finder**. And I never asked about `df -h` either. So, again, my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you run [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) which will do a graphical display of your disk contents. The app is not free but can be used once as a free trial.  This app will map out your entire disk showing where everything is located.  it will take several minutes to completely map your drive.

Comment: OmniDiskSweeper is a free option.